# Postgresql difference between rows

Tags: postgresql, row, difference

My data:

```
id value
1     10
1     20
1     60
2     10
3     10
3     30
```

How to compute column 'change'?

```
id value  change  |    my comment, how to compute
1     10     10   |    20-10
1     20     40   |    60-20
1     60     40   |    default_value-60. In this example default_value=100 
2     10     90   |    default_value-10
3     10     20   |    30-10
3     30     70   |    default_value-30
```

In other words: if row of id is last, then compute 100-value,
else compute next_value-value_now

Comment: Do you have a unqiue or primary key?

Comment: Unique. Imagine that there is date column and I order by it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the value of the "next" (or "previous") row using a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html). The concept of a "next" row only makes sense if you have a column to define an order on the rows. You said you have a date column on which you can order the result. I used the column name `your_date_column` for this. You need to replace that with the actual column name of course.

```
select id, 
       value, 
       lead(value, 1, 100) over (partition by id order by your_date_column) - value as change
from the_table
order by id, your_date_column
```

`lead(value, 1, 100)` says: take the column `value` of the "next" row (that's the `1`). If there is no such row, use the default value `100` instead.

Comment: How about default_value?

Comment: @WingedPanther: should work as well, because `lead(value)` is the same as `lead(value,1,null)`

Answer (score 1):

Join on a subquery and use ROW_NUMBER to find the last value per group

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT id,value,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) rn,
(LEAD(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)-value) change FROM t)
SELECT cte.id,cte.value,
(CASE WHEN cte.change IS NULL THEN 100-cte.value ELSE cte.change END)as change FROM cte LEFT JOIN
(SELECT id,MAX(rn) mrn FROM cte
GROUP BY id) as x
ON x.mrn=cte.rn AND cte.id=x.id
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a2cfd/15)

Comment: Why this complicated nesting of queries? Does it offer any advantage over a "simple" access using `lead()`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not very familiar with full parameters of lead,did it with what I knew.